# Turning off notifications in Hera 5.1 doesn't seem to actually do anything

Tags: notifications

I have both bubbles and sounds turned off in the notifications control panel.  But mail keep sending notification bubbles, as does chrome and spotify.

I'd love to shut all that crap off for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed normally you can disable all notifications, it allows to be focused on these tasks. As you can tell @bo-rislav you can do this with the notification bell menu at the **top right** :

[image]

if you want to disable application sounds not listed in the list of ***Notifications Settings...*** you can. At the end of the list you will have ***OTHER***

[image]

If you only want to disable **MAIL** notifications and if for any others reasons let's keep them active you can do it from the **MAIL** application settings

[image]

But normally if you want disable all notifications, enable **Do Not Distrub** work.

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Usually the settings that you decribe works to stop notifications, but can you try also from the top panel udner the bell icon to set **Do not disturb** also to see if there is any change?